# Doing URL encoding in PHP

Tags: php, url, urlencode

I have two files, `test.php` and `test.html`, with the same content:

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script>
    document.write(encodeURIComponent(';²'));
</script>
```

The output for PHP is `%3B%3F` and for HTML it is `%3B%C2%B2`. How can I get the same result for PHP? How can I transform `;²` to `%3B%C2%B2` using PHP functions?

Comment: wel I have run the same content in php and html file and found the %3B%C2%B2..so can u tell codes are same in both the files?

Comment: Where does PHP factor into this exactly...? `%3F` is the "?" character. I'm suspecting some incorrect handling of encodings here, which turns ² into ?, which you then urlencode. Show your PHP code.

Comment: Thanks! My IDE reverts file encoding from UTF-8 to ANSI back, but still display *²* correctly. If file saved in UTF-8 the output is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [urlencode()](http://php.net/urlencode) function:

```
echo urlencode(';²');
```

The above function outputs `%3B%C2%B2`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function [html_entity_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) and the [HTML entitycode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Character_entity_references_in_HTML) for ² which is `&sup2;`.

Your code will look something like this:

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script>
    document.write(encodeURIComponent(';<?php echo html_entity_decode("&sup2;") ?>'));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! My IDE reverts the file encoding from UTF-8 back to ANSI, but it still displays *²* correctly. If the file saved in UTF-8 the output is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You did not state which PHP function was used, but I would suggest

```
urlencode()
```

*But* you should keep in mind that there are small differences. Guys at http://phpjs.org/functions/urlencode/ made a JavaScript equivalent to phpencode:

```javascript
function urlencode(str) {
  //       discuss at: http://phpjs.org/functions/urlencode/
  //      original by: Philip Peterson
  //      improved by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
  //      improved by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
  //      improved by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
  //      improved by: Lars Fischer
  //         input by: AJ
  //         input by: travc
  //         input by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
  //         input by: Ratheous
  //      bugfixed by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
  //      bugfixed by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
  //      bugfixed by: Joris
  // reimplemented by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
  // reimplemented by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
  //             note: This reflects PHP 5.3/6.0+ behavior
  //             note: Please be aware that this function expects to encode into UTF-8 encoded strings, as found on
  //             note: pages served as UTF-8
  //        example 1: urlencode('Kevin van Zonneveld!');
  //        returns 1: 'Kevin+van+Zonneveld%21'
  //        example 2: urlencode('http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/');
  //        returns 2: 'http%3A%2F%2Fkevin.vanzonneveld.net%2F'
  //        example 3: urlencode('http://www.google.nl/search?q=php.js&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=com.ubuntu:en-US:unofficial&client=firefox-a');
  //        returns 3: 'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.nl%2Fsearch%3Fq%3Dphp.js%26ie%3Dutf-8%26oe%3Dutf-8%26aq%3Dt%26rls%3Dcom.ubuntu%3Aen-US%3Aunofficial%26client%3Dfirefox-a'

  str = (str + '')
    .toString();

  // Tilde should be allowed unescaped in future versions of PHP (as reflected below), but if you want to reflect current
  // PHP behavior, you would need to add ".replace(/~/g, '%7E');" to the following.
  return encodeURIComponent(str)
    .replace(/!/g,   '%21')
    .replace(/'/g,   '%27')
    .replace(/\(/g,  '%28')
    .replace(/\)/g,  '%29')
    .replace(/\*/g,  '%2A')
    .replace(/%20/g, '+');
}
```

Comment: Why is the useless preamble of that function longer than the function body itself...?! O_o And does this really need to be quoted in full here?

Comment: wanted to keep examples and authors in case original link cease to exist

Comment: The `phpjs.org` link is broken (times out): *"The connection has timed out. The server at phpjs.org is taking too long to respond."*